# For-in loops and accessing property values

Tags: javascript

I was given this code:

```
var languages = {
  english: "hello",
  french: "bonjour",
  notALanguage: 4,
  spanish: "hola"
};
```

I have to print out the 3 ways to say hello. I did this:

```
for (var i in languages) {
  if (typeof(languages.i) === "string") {
    console.log(languages.i);
  }
}
```

However, it did not work. On the other hand, this worked:

```
for (var i in languages) {
  if (typeof(languages[i]) === "string") {
    console.log(languages[i]);
  }
}
```

Why? There are two ways to access a property value: either using languages.key or languages["key"]. So why did my code fail, and why did the other code pass?

Comment: *"either using `languages.key` or `languages["key"]`"* – yes, but you don't have either of those. You have `languages[key]`.

Comment: `language.i` is equal to `language["i"]` and not `language[i]`

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Comment: var languages = {
    english: "hello"
}

You need to write languages.english i.e specify the key if you console
languages.i in your case it will be undefined. The Object;s values can only be accessed through obj.keys (type the actual key) or obj['key']. Likewise Arrays in javascript can be accessed either through number or string example Array['0'] or Array[0] since array are regular Objects

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `languages.i` does not work is because it is equivalent to `languages["i"]`. In other words, it uses the name "i" instead of the value of `i`.